# How to solve a QUBO problem by QAOA algorithm with Qiskit Optimization on a real quantum resources/hardware?

Tags: qiskit, optimization, qaoa

I am new to quantum computing, and I am following [this tutorial](https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-optimization/tutorials/03_minimum_eigen_optimizer.html) trying to use Qiskit Optimization 0.6.0 to solve a simple quadratic problem by applying QAOA algorithm.

As stated in the tutorial, I used:

```
algorithm_globals.random_seed = 10598
qaoa_mes = QAOA(sampler=Sampler(), optimizer=COBYLA(), initial_point=[0.0, 0.0])
qaoa = MinimumEigenOptimizer(qaoa_mes)  # using QAOA
exact_result = exact.solve(qubo)
print(exact_result.prettyprint())
```

The result returned as I expected. However, I think this (`MinimumEigenOptimizer` from qiskit optimization) was not executed on a real quantum machine, right? I didn't input any token to connect computing resources, and my account in the IBM quantum platform also didn't show the job.

Therefore, I used the following code to try to connect and execute the optimization through a real quantum resource backend(I chose the `ibmq_qasm_simulator` for testing, but ideally I want to use real hardware):

```
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum",token=token)
backend=service.backend("ibmq_qasm_simulator")
sampler = Sampler(backend=backend)
qaoa_mes = QAOA(sampler=sampler,optimizer=COBYLA())
qaoa = MinimumEigenOptimizer(qaoa_mes)  # using QAOA
exact_result = qaoa.solve(q_model)
print(exact_result.prettyprint())
```

However, the terminal got stuck and didn't return the answer(not even an error message) as in the previous code, even though I could see a job was executed and completed by `ibmq_qasm_simulator` from the IBM quantum platform.

So my question is, what is the correct way to do so if I want to solve a QUBO problem by QAOA algorithm with Qiskit Optimization on real quantum resources/hardware?